# cordova mail plugin for ios stopped working

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer for composing a mail. But it suddenly stopped working and then I removed it. After adding it back when running `cordova build ios` it trows this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while building the ios project.** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/device/app.app/app normal armv7
(1 failure)
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/app.app/app normal i386
(1 failure)

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/compile.js:65:22)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Do you now how to fix this?
I tried changing cordova version to 3.0,3.1,3.2 but it still doesn't work(all other plugins work just fine).

If I add plugins before `cordova build` build passes but email plugin still doesnt work.